# event-properties always empty

Tags: nlog, asp.net-core-webapi

Followed every step [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-(csproj---vs2017)), but my nlog `event-properties` always comes as empty in my log file, both for my loggers and `Microsfot.*` loggers.

I have my layout field like this in my `.config`:

```
layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|  ${message} ${exception}"
```

In my controller action:

```
_logger.LogError(1, "Error Logged");
```

Result:

```
2018-01-12 15:25:11.7495||NlogPro.Controllers.DemoController|ERROR|  Error Logged
```

Comment: Could you try `${all-event-properties}`

Comment: I get `...|EventId_Id=1, EventId_Name=, EventId=1|...`. underscore instead of dot. Is that the correct behavior?

Comment: @legen---waitforit---dary Yes it is. Discovered that dot is not a good character in Json-values, so changed to underscore. Thank you for reporting this, will update the example documentation.

Comment: thanks @RolfKristensen. that answers my question

Answer (score 2):

In summary, use `${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}` instead of `|${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}`.

So `_` instead of `.`.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56709247/nlog-include-eventid-in-log-file

Comment: This has changed in NLog 5: now it's ${event-properties:EventId} (trailing '_Id' removed). See: https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html

Answer (score 1):

This has changed in NLog 5: now it's `${event-properties:EventId}` (trailing '_Id' removed). See: [nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html](https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html)

Notice that you can use `${all-event-properties}` in NLog Target Layout, to investigate the actual property-names of the LogEvent.

Notice that NLog v5 changes to case-insensitive property-lookup, so one should no longer have issues with casing of property-names.